# Uploading an image using AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I tried to upload the image with using AFNetworking3.0.
I have tried to find how to upload image from all stackoverflow and tutorial, but all of these are relative with AFNetworking2.0 and below.
The main focus is that I am going to upload the image to the web site.

Once the image is uploaded, the image url should be existed on web site.

Please see the code below.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *requestManager;

[requestManager POST:KAPIUploadOutfit parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) 
{
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"photo_url" fileName:filename mimeType:@"image/png" error:nil];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        successCB(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        errorCB(CONNECTION_ERROR);
    }];
```

I am not sure what the parameter is about.
Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
          uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
          progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
              // This is not called back on the main queue.
              // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  //Update the progress view
                  [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
              });
          }
          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
              if (error) {
                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              } else {
                  NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
              }
          }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

In this code http://example.com/upload is api where image is going to upload and **file://path/to/image.jpg** is your local image path.

Comment: Can you provide me the file path for instance? I don't know about what give the paramter - "file://path/to/image.jpg".

Comment: I use the  file path - @"file://pic1.png". I think I wrote the wrong the filepath.
Please tell me for instance.
Thanks a lot

Comment: from where you are uploading image ?

Comment: I tested on emulator, the file is located in xcode projcet.
More exactly, 
project directory/Assets.xcassets/content/pic1.imageset/pic1.png

Comment: NSString* str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pic1" ofType:@"png"];
then I debuged it, the str is nil and it crashes.

Comment: How can we manage NSOperationQueue with that , do you have idea , when i upload 5-6 image at a time then ?

Comment: @MikeAlter why you want to use NSOperationQueue for multiple image uploading ?

Comment: i have to upload 10 + images on one button tap so

Comment: @MikeAlter create one array of images paths which are stored in your document directory. then use AFMultipartFormData. and loop through image path array.

Comment: AFMultipartFormData how to use it

Answer (score 1):

In AFNetworking 3.0 upload task works like this.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  // This is not called back on the main queue.
                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      //Update the progress view
                      [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

For complete guide please check [AFNetworking Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replyinig quickly. I am uploading the image with some paramters. For exampe, I am going to register the account, I need uploading the user image with name, email address, etc.
Also, I want to know what is the fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] and URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" in your code. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If we want to call API(using AFNetworking 3.0) for upload images and videos with parameter using same request that time I think would be best class for me

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "MBProgressHUD.h"
    #import "AFNetworking.h"


    @protocol WebServiceDelegate <NSObject>

    @required
    -(void)webserviceCallFinishedWithSuccess:(BOOL)success andResponseObject:(id)responseObj andError:(NSError *)error forWebServiceTag:(NSString *)tagStr;
    @end

    @interface WebService : NSObject<MBProgressHUDDelegate>
    {
        MBProgressHUD   *mbProcess;
        UIView          *view_Process;
    }
    @property(nonatomic, retain)id <WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
    + ( WebService* ) sharedManager;
    -(void)showProgressHUD;
    -(void)dismissProgressHUD;
    -(void)showProgressHUDWithSuccess;
    -(id)initWithView:(UIView *)view andDelegate:(id <WebServiceDelegate>)del;
    -(void)callWebserviceWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)_params
                             action:(NSString*)_action
                        withLoading:(BOOL)loading
                            success:(void(^)(id _responseObject))_success
                            failure:(void(^)(NSError* _error))_failure;


    -(void)PafortRequestWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)_params
                            action:(NSString*)_action
                       withLoading:(BOOL)loading
                           success:(void(^)(id _responseObject))_success
                           failure:(void(^)(NSError* _error))_failure;


    -(void)callWebserviceToUploadImageWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_params
                                       imgParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_imgParams
                                      videoParms:(NSMutableDictionary *)_videoParams
                                          action:(NSString *)_action
                                     withLoading:(BOOL)loading
                                         success:(void (^)(id _responseObject))_success
                                         failure:(void (^)(NSError * _error))_failure;


    @end


// This is .m class 
    #import "WebService.h"
    #import "ProgressHUD.h"
    @implementation WebService
    @synthesize delegate;

    -(id)initWithView:(UIView *)view andDelegate:(id <WebServiceDelegate>)del
    {
        self = [super init];

        if(self)
        {
            view_Process = view;
            self.delegate = del;
        }
        return self;
    }
    + ( WebService* ) sharedManager
    {
        __strong static WebService* sharedObject = nil ;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken ;

        dispatch_once( &onceToken, ^{
            sharedObject = [ [ WebService alloc ] init ] ;
        } ) ;
        return sharedObject ;
    }

    -(void)showProgressHUD{
        [theAppDelegate.window endEditing:YES];

        [ProgressHUD hudColor:THEME_BLACK_COLOR];
        [ProgressHUD backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1]];
        [ProgressHUD statusColor:WHITE_COLOR];

        [ProgressHUD hudColor:THEME_BLACK_COLOR];
        [ProgressHUD spinnerColor:WHITE_COLOR];

        [ProgressHUD show:LocalizedString(@"Please Wait") Interaction:NO];
    }
    -(void)showProgressHUDWithSuccess{
        [theAppDelegate.window endEditing:YES];

        [ProgressHUD hudColor:THEME_BLACK_COLOR];
        [ProgressHUD backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1]];
        [ProgressHUD statusColor:WHITE_COLOR];

        [ProgressHUD hudColor:THEME_BLACK_COLOR];
        [ProgressHUD spinnerColor:WHITE_COLOR];

        [ProgressHUD showSuccess:LocalizedString(@"Success!")];
    }
    -(void)dismissProgressHUD{
        [ProgressHUD dismiss];
    }
    -(void)callWebserviceWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)_params
                             action:(NSString*)_action
                        withLoading:(BOOL)loading
                            success:(void(^)(id _responseObject))_success
                            failure:(void(^)(NSError* _error))_failure
    {

        if(loading)
        {
            [self showProgressHUD];
        }

        NSString *url = BASE_URL;//[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:_action];
        [_params setValue:_action forKey:@"method"];
        [_params setValue:[[SingletonClass sharedManager] get_user_id] forKey:PM_USER_ID];
        [_params setValue:PM_USER forKey:PM_USER_TYPE];
        [_params setValue:@"1" forKey:@"device_type"];


        DLog(@"API:>>> %@",url);
        DLog(@"PARAMS:>>>%@",_params);
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/json",@"text/jsvascript",@"text/html", nil];

        [manager POST:url parameters:_params progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
            if(loading)
            {
                [ProgressHUD dismiss];
            }
            DLog(@"Response : >>> %@",responseObject);

            if ([[responseObject valueForKey:RESPONSE_STATUS] intValue] == 1) {
                if (_success) {
                    _success (responseObject);
                }
            }else{
                if(loading)
                {
                    showAlertWithErrorMessage([responseObject valueForKey:RESPONSE_MESSAGE]);
                }
                NSError *error;
                if (_failure) {
                    _failure (error);
                }
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            DLog(@"Error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            if(loading)
            {
                [ProgressHUD dismiss];
                [self showFailureMessage:error];

            }

            if (_failure) {
                _failure (error);
            }
        }];

    }


    -(void)showFailureMessage:(NSError*)error{
        if ([[error description] rangeOfString:@"The request timed out."].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(@"The request timed out, please verify your internet connection and try again.");
        }
        else if ([[error description] rangeOfString:@"The server can not find the requested page"].location != NSNotFound || [[error description] rangeOfString:@"A server with the specified hostname could not be found."].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(@"Unable to reach to the server, please try again after few minutes");
        }
        else if([[error description] rangeOfString:@"The network connection was lost."].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(@"The network connection was lost, please try again.");

        }
        else if([[error description] rangeOfString:@"The Internet connection appears to be offline."].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(@"The Internet connection appears to be offline.");

        }
        else if([[error description] rangeOfString:@"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(@"Server error!");
        }
        else
        {
            showAlertWithErrorMessage(@"Unable to connect, please try again!");

        }
    }

    -(void)callWebserviceToUploadImageWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_params
                                       imgParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_imgParams
                                      videoParms:(NSMutableDictionary *)_videoParams
                                          action:(NSString *)_action
                                     withLoading:(BOOL)loading
                                         success:(void (^)(id _responseObject))_success
                                         failure:(void (^)(NSError * _error))_failure{

        if(loading)
        {

            [self showProgressHUD];

        }

        NSString *urlString = BASE_URL;//[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:_action];
        [_params setValue:_action forKey:@"method"];
        [_params setValue:[[SingletonClass sharedManager] get_user_id] forKey:PM_USER_ID];
        [_params setValue:PM_USER forKey:PM_USER_TYPE];
        [_params setValue:@"1" forKey:@"device_type"];

        DLog(@"API:>>> %@",urlString);
        DLog(@"PARAMS:>>>%@",_params);

        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        // [urlRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type: application/json"]
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [_params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSString *object, BOOL *stop) {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }];

        [_imgParams enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSData *object, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
                if (object.length > 0) {
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    DLog(@"Timestamp:%@",TimeStamp);
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",key,TimeStamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:object]];
                }

            }
        }];

        [_videoParams enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSData *object, BOOL *stop) {
            if (object.length > 0) {
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                DLog(@"Timestamp:%@",TimeStamp);
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.mp4\"\r\n",key,TimeStamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:object]];
            }
        }];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
        AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
        manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 120.0f;


        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:urlRequest progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(loading)
            {
                [ProgressHUD dismiss];
            }
            if (error) {

                [self showFailureMessage:error];

                DLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                if( _failure ){
                    _failure( error) ;
                }
            } else {
                DLog(@"response = %@", responseObject);
                if ([[responseObject valueForKey:RESPONSE_STATUS] intValue] == 1) {
                    if (_success) {
                        _success (responseObject);
                    }
                }else{
                    if( _failure ){
                        _failure( error) ;
                    }
                    showAlertWithErrorMessage([responseObject valueForKey:RESPONSE_MESSAGE]);
                }
            }
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }
```