# Upload image to server from imagePickerController AFNetWorking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, uiimagepickercontroller, afnetworking-3

How can I upload an image to server from `imagePickerController` with `AFNetworking`? I tried this:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:photo.data name:@"photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];
```

but from where i must to get name and fileName ?

If someone could help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35956496/1776470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `AFURLRequestSerialization.h` file to read the documentation of the method you're using:

```
/**
 Appends the HTTP header `Content-Disposition: file; filename=#{filename}; name=#{name}"` and `Content-Type: #{mimeType}`, followed by the encoded file data and the multipart form boundary.

 @param data The data to be encoded and appended to the form data.
 @param name The name to be associated with the specified data. This parameter must not be `nil`.
 @param fileName The filename to be associated with the specified data. This parameter must not be `nil`.
 @param mimeType The MIME type of the specified data. (For example, the MIME type for a JPEG image is image/jpeg.) For a list of valid MIME types, see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/. This parameter must not be `nil`.
 */
```

Just set the filename to whatever you want to receive it on the backend. In case it doesn't require to have a special file name just give it anything like `@"photo.jpg"`

Comment: Thank you for help.