# Showing the status of uploading images in ios

Tags: ios, database, multithreading

I want to upload some images to the server. But I want to do all the things in the background so that I can do other works when the data uploading to the server. And I want to show the status in another view controller. How to do it?

Comment: Just create a singleton class for image uploading

Comment: Thanks. Any recommended site for references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947930/uploading-an-image-using-afnetworking-3-0

Comment: should I use any database to store and show status of uploading the image